# NSPredicate for decimals numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

Can someone give me NSPredicate for validating string which are of the form:
1. Atleast one digit (0-9)
2. Followed by one or none of ".(0-9)"

So basically I want string like this to be valid:

```
2.34
84
1.0
2314234
3214.23123
```

Thanks.

Comment: NSString *predicateString = @"[0-9].([0-9])?";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
NSString *predicateString = @"[0-9]+\\.[0-9]$"; 
NSPredicate *numberTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", predicateString]; 
BOOL isNumber = [numberTest evaluateWithObject:string];
```

Instead of using `NSPredicate`, you can use the `NSScanner` method `- (BOOL)scanFloat:(float *)floatValue`.